# Nested struct in templated class with std::map::const_iterator?

Tags: c++, templates, nested, stdmap

The folowing code generates a syntax error at the line where the iterator is declared:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
  public:

    struct B
    {
       int x, y, z;
    };

    void a()
    {
        std::map<int, B>::const_iterator itr; // error: ; expected before itr
    }

    std::vector<T> v;
    std::map<int, B> m;
};
```

This only happens when A is a templated class. What's wrong with this code? If I move B out of A, the code compiles fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a typename:

```
 typename std::map<int, B>::const_iterator itr;
```

The iterator is a dependant type (depends on B) and when you have this situation the compiler requires you to clarify it with a typename.

There is a reasonable discussion of the issue [here](http://womble.decadentplace.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#dependent).

Comment: +1. Can I suggest adding the words "inside a template definition" after "when you have this situation"?